# Get dependency version introduced by Spring Boot starter

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I'm using Gradle and the Gradle Boot plugin, version 1.2.5.RELEASE. Is it possible to somehow get hang of the various versions of the dependencies that are imported? For instance, get the 4.3.10.Final for the hibernate-core version?

Comment: this isn't really a spring-boot problem but a gradle problem, not sure how to list deps with gradle, but it should be able to print a dep tree somehow

Comment: I think it is a spring-boot question. Gradle by default doesn't have a dependency-management section or any properties which would give the versions back. But, spring wrote their own plugin (https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) and it does support what I'm asking: https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin#changing-the-value-of-a-version-property. I can't find any spring boot properties in the starter boms, hence the question if it is possible.

Comment: I finally found out where the properties are stored: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$version.